# Ruby: How to manually set up seed data for a one-to-many and a many-to-many relationship to use active record

Tags: ruby, activerecord, many-to-many, one-to-many, seeding

I am trying to figure out how to set up my Seeds.rb data manually. With this data, I'm trying to connect the following relationships: A doctor has many patients , a patient has one doctor, a patient has many charts and a doctor has access to the charts through patients.

I'm not understanding how to connect the three different models when i'm creating the data manually.

- **For the Doctor.rb model:**

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :patients
    has_many :charts , through: :patients
end
```

- **Migration for Doctor**

```
class CreateDoctors < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
      create_table :doctors do |t|
        t.string :name , :speciality 
        t.integer :license_number
      end 
  end
end
```

- **Patient.rb model:**

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :doctor
    has_many :charts
end
```

- **Migration for Patient**

```
class CreatePatients < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :patients do |t|
      t.string :name , :gender, :description, :medication
      t.integer :age
      t.float :account_balance
      t.integer :doctor_id , chart_id
      
    end
  end
end
```

- **Chart.rb model**

```
class Chart < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :patient
    belongs_to :doctor
end
```

- **Migration for Chart**

```
class CreateCharts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
        create_table :charts do |t|
          t.string  :chart
          t.integer :patient_id , :doctor_id
          
       
    end
  end
end
```

**example of seed data:** (im not sure how to connect the three)

```
Doctor.create(name: "Aaron Yan", speciality: "Marriage & Family "  , license_number: 85477)

Patient.create(name: "Danielle Marsh", age: 28, gender: "F", account_balance: 44.23 , description: "Panic Disorder, Insomnia", medication:"Tofranil 25 mg")

Chart.create(description: "this patient exhibits the following symptoms, treatment plan is etc")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack overflow!
To create related data, you just need to save the result to variables and add them using the relationships. eg:

```
doctor = Doctor.create(name: "Aaron Yan", speciality: "Marriage & Family "  , license_number: 85477)

patient = doctor.patients.create(name: "Danielle Marsh", age: 28, gender: "F", account_balance: 44.23 , description: "Panic Disorder, Insomnia", medication:"Tofranil 25 mg")

patient.charts.create(description: "this patient exhibits the following symptoms, treatment plan is etc")
```